# apply custom expanding function on multiple columns groupby pandas (exp weighted mean & std)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation, exponential

I am trying to calculate an expanding exponential average and standard deviation with a defined custom function that needs multiple columns as parameters, all by group.

*Note: this is an example, I am not asking for a statistical validation if this is correct or not.*

**Example Data & Code**

Here is a bit of code of how to reproduce the data I am using to test my custom functions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# =============================================================================
#  custom functions
# =============================================================================

def exp_decay(t, xi):
    return(np.exp(- xi * t))

def wmean(x, t, xi=1e-3):
    # get un-normalized decayments
    w = exp_decay(t, xi)
    lambd = w / np.sum(w)
    
    # get wmean
    wmean = np.dot(lambd, x)
    
    return(wmean)

def wstd(x, t, xi=1e-3):
    # get un-normalized decayments
    w = exp_decay(t, xi)
    lambd = w / np.sum(w)
    
    # get w std
    wmean = np.dot(lambd, x)
    unbais_const = 1/(1 - np.sum(lambd**2))
    sqrd_diff = (x-wmean)**2
    wstd = np.sqrt(unbais_const * np.dot(lambd, sqrd_diff))
    
    return(wstd)

# =============================================================================
# data
# =============================================================================
# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('taxis')

# vars 2 use
VAR_GROUP = 'pickup_borough'
VAR_TIME = 'hours_diff'
VAR_X = 'fare'

# wrangle data
df = (
  df.
  dropna(
      subset=[VAR_GROUP]
  ).assign(
      date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['pickup']), # coarce to date
  ).sort_values(
      [VAR_GROUP, 'date'], ascending=True, ignore_index=True
  ).
  assign(
      # hours diff with repect the last ride in each group
      hours_diff = lambda x: 
          (x.groupby(VAR_GROUP)['date'].transform('max') - x['date']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
  )
)
```

Here is the part I am struggling: I want to use `wmean` & `wstd` in an `expanding()` function over the group `VAR_GROUP` using `VAR_TIME` as the time variabale decayment and `VAR_X` as the objective variable to aggregate over.

My approach was to use `expanding(method='table')` over the subset of variables I need but I'm getting `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional` as error. This is the code I used:

```
# subset
df_subset = df[[VAR_GROUP, VAR_TIME, VAR_X]].copy()
          
# problem: use custom expanding function with multiple columns
XI = 1e-2

df_subset = (
    df_subset.
    assign(
        wavg = lambda x: 
            x.groupby(
                VAR_GROUP
            ).expanding(
                method='table'
            ).apply(
                wmean(x[VAR_X], x[VAR_TIME], xi=XI)
            ).reset_index(
                drop=True
            ),
                
        wstd = lambda x: 
            x.groupby(
                VAR_GROUP
            ).expanding(
                method='table'
            ).apply(
                wstd(x[VAR_X], x[VAR_TIME], xi=XI)
            ).reset_index(
                drop=True
            )
    )
       
)
```

I am begging for help! Thank you!

PD: If this can also be used in a `rolling()` would be awesome!!!